# How to run 'set' or 'source' with Ammonite Script

Tags: bash, scala, ammonite, scala-script

I want to do the following with Ammonite:

```
set -a
source .my-env
docker-compose up -d
```

My Solution looks like:

```
  %("set", "-a")
  %("source", "./devops/it.env")
  %("docker-compose", ...)
```

The first 2 lines do not work, I get `No such file or directory`.

I tried different variations:

```
  %bash("set", "-a")
  %sh("set", "-a")
  %("bash", "set", "-a")
```

The commands work in `bash`.

How is this done with Ammonite correctly?

Comment: Just a guess (since I don't use Ammonite): Since there are no executables named `set` and `source` in your path -  after all,  they are internal bash commands -  Ammonite can not run them.

Comment: For the same reason `"source"` would not work - just use http://ammonite.io/#EnvironmentVariables to set env vars up in your script.